# Group Symbols Together during order_by

Tags: django, django-orm

When using `order_by` in the Django ORM it seems that it is ignoring symbol characters in the text when sorting.

For example with the folowing query set.

```
+--------+
| name   |
+--------+
| 'A'    |
| '@B'   |
| 'C'    |
| 'D'    |
| '@E'   |
| 'F'    |
| '$G'   |
| '$H'   |
+--------+
```

When using `Item.objects.all().order_by("name")`, the list is returned exactly as you see above.

How do i order that list where the symbols are sorted together like so:

`A,C,D,F,@B,@E,$G,$H`

Comment: That is not the Django ORM, that is the *collation* of the column.

Comment: no, I mean that the exact ordering rules are not determined by Django, but the collation of the database.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem oh lol im sorry. i see what youre saying but is there not a way to group those from an sql level?

Comment: If you are familiar with writing sql you can use the .raw method

Comment: @Chris yea i am but even that appears to be subject to the same limitation as willem was saying. the database itself has a default collation that itll use. id rather not change that either if it can be avoided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the collation using the [`Collate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/database-functions/#collate) database function, for example:

```
from django.db.models.functions import Collate

...
items = Item.objects.order_by(Collate("name", "Latin1_General_CS_AI"))
```